# inline css working while external style sheet isn't on textarea html element

Tags: html, css

I've got a text area whose font size will only increase if i do inline styling. I can't understand what the error could be. Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="letter_text" name="content_area"> </textarea>
</div>
```

If I do this it works:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="letter_text" name="content_area" style="font-size: 30pt;"></textarea>
```

But not this, on my external style sheet. Here the textbox font pt is unaffected:

```
textarea
{
    font-size: 30pt;
}
```

Comment: Post the link to the style sheet.

Comment: have you verified that you're including the style sheet without error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are using bootstrap CSS, and it works with inline styling - this is an issue of specificity.

Bootstrap adds the `font-size` via `.form-control { font-size: 14px; }`

If you want to overwrite this, simply be more specific. Use something like

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/2wfRE/), it works.

```
textarea.form-control {
    font-size: 30pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible there is a more specific selector dictating the font size on that textarea, but without a complete example, we wouldn't know. I would suggest reading up on [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).